# FFMPEG concatenate 2 random and different videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, aspect-ratio, video-editing

I am trying to make an app in which users can send a video and it will be concatenated with other videos automatically. So the videos are in random formats, but I am converting them before concatenation using this command :

```
ffmpeg -y -i {orginalVideo.itsExtention} -vcodec wmv2 4.wmv
```

For the concatenation I have the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i concat.wmv -i 4.wmv -filter_complex "[0:0][0:1][1:0][1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" output.wmv
```

but I get the following error

```
Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 640x480, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1080x1920, SAR 1:1)

Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
```

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The videos have to be the same size (pixel dimensions, that is). The output stream can't change sizes midway through. So resize one (or both) to the desired size.

e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -y -i {orginalVideo.itsExtention} -vf scale=640:480 -vcodec wmv2 4.wmv
```

And see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling for more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I achieve that

Comment: @AbibadAbdou I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Worked like a charm ,Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Using a separate step to scale is not efficient and will introduce another generational loss of quality if using a lossy encoder.

Since you're already re-encoding you can scale in the same command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i concat.wmv -i 4.wmv -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1080:1920,setsar=1[v1];[0:v][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.wmv
```

Or you could use a more complex command to avoid stretching or squishing due to the aspect ratio differences:

```
ffmpeg -y -i concat.wmv -i 4.wmv -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1];[0:v][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.wmv
```